# Password hiding in shell script

Tags: shell

I have created a shell script as given below.And I need to hide the password, which i will be given when the script prompt for that. If I run the below script written inside the single quotes in my local machine, it will hide the password. But if I add the SSH part it wont.

What should I do for hiding password ?

> ```
> ssh root@10.3.2.0 'echo -n Password:;
> read -s password;
> echo;
> echo $password;
> '
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `-t` option to ssh to force tty allocation.

```
ssh -t root@10.3.2.0 'echo -n Password:;
read -s password;
echo;
echo $password;'
```

EDIT: explanation of suggested solution

If not running a login-session but just a command instead by default SSH won't allocate a pseudo terminal device for the running process.
This behavior is not a bug a all, but delibarately chosen by design.

This way it is possible to pass binary data uninterpreted between different machines.
Maybe something like:

```
ssh whoever@wherever 'cat remote_file' | local_program
```

Passing data between two machines this way would almost be impossible if the data was filtered by a terminal driver in between - Think of the tons of escape sequences you would have to care about !

Without any terminal allocated there is no way of hiding user input. Any attempts to `stty something` will fail, as there isn't any terminal at all!

To make ssh allocate a pseudo terminal even if not running in a login-session you have to pass the `-t` parameter to force tty allocation.

Comment: Seems like, I got a hang of what is going on, though a bit. But still the input is useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Better use ssh keys, that way, no need to pass a password with the help of a `ssh-agent`. see a good how-to : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys

Comment: Actually I just need to hide what i have given.Not specifically for password.If there is an option for entering bank account number and if I want to hid it from others, what should i do for hiding it.

Comment: @sputnick: sry, that would be me then. I "downvoted" (nice term I just learned) because the answer while definately a good idea to operate ones _ssh_ passwords/keys it still doesn't fit to the problem described: qerying for _any_ kind of password e-mail file-encryption or whatever. To repeat while sure a pretty perfect solution to the ssh key handling problem I tought the answer might be missleading in respect to the given question.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to scripts, though I guess this might can help you :

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -n "Enter Password : "
stty -echo
read password < /dev/tty
stty echo
echo
echo -n "Enter Password again : "
stty -echo
read password1 < /dev/tty
stty echo
echo
echo "Password Entered are : $password and $password1"
```

Comment: IMHO this wont work either as in non-interactive mode there won't be any pseudo terminal allocated on the target machine thus `stty` and the `-s` option failing to work.

Comment: @mikyra : Wish I really could understand one bit of what you talking about. I am too new to LINUX, so you can guess regarding how new I am to scripts :-). I just learned this thingy few days ago, so I thought might be this would work. I am really not sure, just wanted to give one more option to the OP to look at.

Comment: based on the feedback given, I updated the post made above with some kind of rationale. Take a look there if you are still curious.